# Sending an email through outlook's smtp server

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, outlook, smtp

I've researched extensively and have found no working solutions for my currently problem. I'm wanting to send an email through my windows live email using their SMTP server. I get the error:

"Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.3 Requested action aborted; user not authenticated"

I've tried working with my firewall, trying to enable the SMTP settings in my account, and a couple other solutions I've found on this site and others but nothing works. In my outlook/windows account's recent activity I do not see an SMTP access, only my current sign in, even though it says I'm connecting.

I'm not opposed to using another SMTP server
I'm working with C#/ASP.NET
This is my code:

```
        public static void Email(string name, string recipient, string address, string email, string info)
    {
        MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
        mailMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
        // From
        MailAddress mailAddress = new MailAddress("user@live.com");
        mailMsg.From = mailAddress;

        //Content
        mailMsg.Subject = "Secret Santa";
        mailMsg.Body = name + ", your target is " + recipient + ". Please spread the holiday cheer with a soft cap of $20! From an automated mail service";

        //SmtpClient
        SmtpClient smtpConnection = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 587);
        smtpConnection.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user@live.com", "password");
        smtpConnection.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        smtpConnection.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpConnection.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtpConnection.Send(mailMsg);
    }
```

Comment: Have you seen the following blog post: [Send Email using Hotmail/Live/Office 365 in C#](https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
smtpConnection.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user@live.com", "password");

smtpConnection.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

You provide your own credentials for authentication, so you have to set UseDefaultCredentials to `false`. Otherwise `SmtpClient` cannot authenticate and you get error.